# Firebase as an android app backend

Tags: android, firebase

I am working on an Android application and planning to use Firebase as backend.

My main question if I need any other backend resources (hosting, server side scripting, etc) in addition to Firebase.

In front end my app will collect some user data, convert it to Json (as far as i know Firebase uses Json) and sent to Firebase.

I will create and maintain a database in Firebase.

And the main question: can i run a code/script/logic on Firebase to compare user data against the data in database. Then return a result to that specific user.

This question arises especially after Google introduced Firebase "functions": https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/.

Or do i need an additional backend service like AWS?

And after all would you recommend to use a native backend instead of using Firebase.

Thanks in advance for support.

Answer (score 2):

Good for you because Firebase offers a `Real Time Database` and the new one which it also good to use `Firestore`. You dont need a Server for this, everything will be done under firebase databases via your app's code under some set of rules. Check for this quote from Firebase Official Site on RealTime Database from [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

> The Firebase Realtime Database can be accessed directly from a mobile device or web browser; there’s no need for an application server. Security and data validation are available through the Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules, expression-based rules that are executed when data is read or written.

More over because you are making a new app the best way is to use `Firestore` as your database because in addition to synchronization across multiple device it is scalable and more over its new (beta now). So if you are planning to make apps where you will have a lot of users its time to get to know `Firestore`. If you want to compare the two database differences [check this link.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) For more information check the [official firebase site here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)

Comment: what about running code/script/logic to return a result to specific user?

Comment: You can do that using your android app code in java! And save to the database directly using code. Or perhaps you want something else like long running calculations????

Comment: let me be more specific:

Comment: let me be more specific: i do not want to maintain database in user phone as it is big and has to be updated daily. 

just to extremely simplify the use case lets say app collected specific user data and it is an integer with value 123. and we have our database in cloud (firebase) that have data entries corresponding to user data. i need a script to query this database to find the value corresponding to user data (123). and then the result will be returned to user.

Comment: my question should i run this script in local app java code or should i run a javascript code (is it possible?) in cloud (firebase). regarding app performance which one is faster as running this query in local app java will create several requests and repossess between app and firebase.

Comment: Firebase is a trusted service and it is well optimized for performance and easy of coding. So if you real want to save data and easy querying you just should RealTime datastore or Google cloud Firestore.